# Import CSV in PGAdmin 3 with autoincrement ID

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.5, import-csv

I want to import CSV in PGAdmin III with ID field auto increment. I am not able to do it. The CSV contains a column as ID with null values.

need help.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why hasn't it worked/what error did you get?

Comment: I created a simple table named person in PGAdmin 3. The columns were ID, Name and Region. I assigned ID as primary key and by default its not null. Then I created a CSV file with same columns and I kept the ID column blank. The name and the region column contains data. I actually wanted to import the CSV in the database and the ID field should be auto incremented. While importing I took the format CSV and encoding UTF8. It gives me an error as null value in column "ID" violates not null constrains.